# Downloading worksheets from tableau in excel

Tags: excel, web-scraping

I am trying to download the worksheets in a usable excel format. I am getting the data in an excel cell only. Here's the code I am using.

code-

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = 'https://public.tableau.com/views/ElectricityGeneration_0/Source?%3Adisplay_static_image=y&%3AbootstrapWhenNotified=true&%3Aembed=true&%3Alanguage=en-US&:embed=y&:showVizHome=n&:apiID=host0'

ts = TS()

ts.loads(url)

workbook = ts.getWorkbook()

data =[]

for t in workbook.worksheets:

    print(f"worksheet name : {t.name}") #show worksheet name

    print(t.data) #show dataframe for this worksheet

    data.append(t.data)
 
Data=pd.DataFrame(data)

Data.to_excel
```

Comment: You are obtaining a dataframe (t.data) then you append that dataframe to a list. Then you get another dataframe which you append to a list. So you have a list of dataframes, with different headers.. did you hope to merge them somehow, by running pd.Dataframe() against that list? I'm not sure what your end goal is..?

Comment: What does *usable excel format* means to you? Maybe, writing a dataframe per different sheet in excel? Please explain your end goal.

Comment: I have to analyze data from the these worksheets. I am trying to download this data in excel format. I am not aware of how to download this data in excel format, I tried appending the data to a list, but that is not giving any usable results. I basically want to know how to download it

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus, are you aware of any such way to download the workbook in excel? It would be very helpful.